Tblr Multiple rows/columns alignment
I am trying to create this using LaTex.  It comes from Mark Sparks Daily Lessons and Assessments. I have messing with it for an hour and wonder how I can clean my code up and if the code I have is efficient.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\title{Tables for LaTex Homework}
\author{Nicholas Bennett}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

    \begin{tblr}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} For questions 5-9, use the function \(f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+2}\) & \\
        \hline
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Find \(f'(x)\) by finding \(\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\)  &   Find the slope of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-2\) \\[2in]  \hline &  Find the slope of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-1\) \\[2in] \hline    &    Find the equation of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-1\) \\[2in] \hline
        \SetCell[c=2]{l} Find \(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\), where \(a=-1\) & \\[2in]
            \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}

Any help would be appreciated.
Table: 

Your MWE has some typos
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\title{Tables for LaTex Homework}
\author{Nicholas Bennett}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={XX},
        hlines,
        vlines,
        row{1} = {0.4in},
        row{2-5} = {2in,h},
        }
        \SetCell[c=2]{c} For questions 5-9, use the function \(f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+2}\) & \\
        \SetCell[r=3]{l} Find \(f'(x)\) by finding \(\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\)  &   Find the slope of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-2\) \\
        &  Find the slope of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-1\) \\
        &    Find the equation of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-1\) \\
        \SetCell[c=2]{l} Find \(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\), where \(a=-1\) & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}


EDIT: Option 2. Same output
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\title{Tables for LaTex Homework}
\author{Nicholas Bennett}
\date{May 2024}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={XX},
        hlines,
        vlines,
        row{1} = {0.4in},
        row{2-5} = {2in,h},
        cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{c},
        cell{2}{1} = {r=3}{l},
        cell{Z}{1} = {c=2}{l},
        }
        For questions 5-9, use the function \(f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+2}\) & \\
        Find \(f'(x)\) by finding \(\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\)
        & Find the slope of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-2\) \\
        & Find the slope of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-1\) \\
        & Find the equation of the tangent line drawn to the graph of \(f(x)\) at \(x=-1\) \\
        Find \(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\), where \(a=-1\) & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}


Thank you! Sorry about the typos, didn't realize I had them.
